# How to get user email id through username by using csv file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

By using csv/xls file we will upload usernames then in download we have to get user email_id to that specific user. How can I do? any help

Comment: Which frontend framework are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, AngularJS we are using